# Is it possible to create iBatis/MyBatis artifacts for Views in SQL?

Tags: sql, view, ibatis

I am new to iBatis. I want to know -

1. Is it possible to create ibatis Artifacts (.java files) for views in SQL Server 2005?
2. Is querying those views will be same as querying the tables?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could, there is no difference between table and view while querying with ibatis and mybatis.

Comment: If views are handled just like tables, how does one avoid sub-selects? I've heard these were generally inefficient and to be avoided. I mean if you had a view X and you wanted to implement it in MyBatis, wouldn't you essentially wind up doing SELECT * FROM X where X itself executes SELELCTs and JOIN's, etc. etc., i.e. a nested SELECT?